# Setting Timeout in ComponentDidUpdate in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I stuck on the one issue I cannot solve by myself. Namely, I'm trying to figure out how set Timeout in the moment I would like to change a state. In other words, I would like to change it after 5 seconds and this should happen in the place where I'm changing the state, ie. in ComponentDidUpdate lifecycle. Is that possible or should I rewrite my code?

Also, is it a good practice to put "if" logic in render method like in the code below?

Thank you in advance!

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../../sass/main.scss';

class TypeAnimation extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            sec: 0,
            sec2: 0,
            currentSentence: 0,
            blinker: '|',
            blinker2: null
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.firstSentenceInterval = setInterval(() => {
            this.setState({
                sec2: this.state.sec2 + 1,
            });
        }, 100);

        this.textInterval = setInterval(() => {
            this.setState(
                prevState => ({ 
                    sec: prevState.sec !== this.props.text[0].length &&
                         this.state.sec2 === this.props.text[0].length ?
                         prevState.sec + 1 : 0,
                    currentSentence: prevState.sec === this.props.text[0].length ?
                    prevState.currentSentence + 1 : prevState.currentSentence,
                })
            ); 
        }, 100);
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        if (this.state.sec2 === this.props.text[0].length &&
            this.state.blinker !== null) { 
            this.setState({    //I would like to change those states but after 5 seconds 
                blinker: null,
                blinker2: '|'
            });
            clearInterval(this.firstSentenceInterval);
        } 
    }


    render() {

        const incomingFirstSen = this.props.text[0];
        const firstSentence = incomingFirstSen.substr(0, this.state.sec2);

        let otherSentences;
        const nextSentences = this.props.text.slice(1);
        const currentText = nextSentences[this.state.currentSentence];

        if (this.state.sec2 !== incomingFirstSen.length) {
            otherSentences = null;
        } else if (this.state.currentSentence !== nextSentences.length) {
            otherSentences = currentText.substr(0, this.state.sec);
        } else {
            clearInterval(this.textInterval);
            otherSentences = nextSentences[nextSentences.length - 1];
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <h2>
                    {firstSentence}
                    <span className="blinker"> {this.state.blinker} </span>
                </h2>
                <h2>
                    {otherSentences}
                    <span className='blinker'> {this.state.blinker2} </span>
                </h2>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default TypeAnimation;
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use setInterval?  The `setTimeout(expression, timeout)` runs the code/function once after the timeout whereas 'setInterval(expression, timeout)` runs the code/function in intervals, with the length of the timeout between them.

Comment: It is opinion based question about conditions in render. I do not think (now) that it is bad. But for me `const` looks better than `let`, so you can rewrite it with ternary op: `const v = c ? t : f`. But it is only the opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fragment of your code snippet have an error wich cause wrong state value:

```js
this.firstSentenceInterval = setInterval(() => {
  this.setState({
    sec2: this.state.sec2 + 1,
  });
}, 100);
```

It must be rewrited with:

```js
this.firstSentenceInterval = setInterval(() => {
  this.setState( prevState => {
    sec2: prevState.sec2 + 1,
  });
}, 100);
```

Your question:

> I'm trying to figure out how set Timeout in the moment I would like to change a state

You need add watcher on state change and recreate timer if it was already created:

```js
componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  if( this.state.counter != nextState.counter ) {
    if( this.textTimer ) clearTimeout(this.textTimer)
    this.textTimer = setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState( prevState => {
        sec2: prevState.sec2 + 1,
      });
    })
  }
```

Comment: I tried setTimeOut on componentWillUpdate and it is working unexpectedly lots of times, maybe using at regular react component function will good

Comment: The `setTimeout` function must be called only on some condition in `componentWillUpdate` handler. For example when `counter` is changed as in snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

Do not update state in `componentDidUpdate`. The component have just rendered and you will cause it to render again.

Instead, you should set state in `componentWillMount`. Just use a normal `setTimeout` in `componentWillMount` to update the state.

It's normal to put "if" logic in the render function if you need to check the current state, don't worry :)

Comment: Do not confuse `componentWillMount` and `componentWillUpdate`. If you suggest to replace `componentDidUpdate` with `componentWillMount` you might mean `componentWillUpdate` instead.

Comment: No I don't confuse, You cannot setState in `componentWillUpdate`.
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillupdate

Comment: Method `componentDidUpdate` is called when state or props is changed. And `componentWillMount` is called when component is mounted - it is different sence. How it can replace each other?

Comment: And his code does not call `setState` directly but as timeout handler - so it will be ok with `setState` sure.

Comment: From the docs you reference: "You may call `setState()` immediately in `componentDidUpdate()` but note that it must be wrapped in a condition like in the example above, or you’ll cause an infinite loop."